# Код curses не работает Python

Tags: python, консоль, curses

Изучаю curses по гайду. Буквально скопировал участок кода из видео, и запускаю также как и сказано: через команду python в терминале

**test1.py:**

```
from curses import wrapper

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr("Hello World!")
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```

В видео, этот код работал, когда я пытаюсь его запустить
[image: Ничего не происходит]

Curses установлен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ide ошибок никаких не показывает

Что может быть не так

Comment: Покажите ссылку на тот скрипт откуда вы копировали свой, и опишите проблему подробнее, что значит не работает?